# How to get items within a div container to stack when browser is resized

Tags: html, css

Currently, I am having trouble get my main content to scale up and down during browser resizing. The navbar is adjusting just fine, but the other content is not. Whenever I resize my browser the div elements seem to be staying the same size and not adjusting with everything else. Does anyone have any suggestions on what I am doing wrong or what else I could try?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#blue {
  background-color: #57afb5;
  max-width: 470px;
  height: 350px;
  flex: 0 0 65%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#dark-green {
  background-color: #29914c;
  max-width: 470px;
  height: 350px;
  flex: 0 0 65%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#green {
  background-color: #91e3ad;
  max-width: 470px;
  height: 350px;
  flex: 0 0 65%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#orange {
  background-color: #c98a32;
  max-width: 470px;
  height: 350px;
  flex: 0 0 65%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#top {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 2%;
}

#bottom {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 2%;
}

.main-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.footer {
  margin-top: 8%;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}


/* responsive web design*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  #blue {
    width: 50%;
  }
  #dark-green {
    width: 50%;
  }
  #green {
    width: 50%;
  }
  #orange {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .footer {
    width: 100%;
  }
}


/*end of responsive web design*/
```

```html
<div class='main-content'>
  <div id='Navbar_Link-Toggle' style='font-size: 20px'>
    <i id='main' class='fas fa-bars'></i>
  </div>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='Navbar'>
      <a class='links' href=''>FOOD</a>
      <a class='links' href=''>FUN</a>
      <img id='center-logo' src='img/SAMO.png'>
      <a class='links' href=''>HISTORY</a>
      <a class='links' href=''>LOCATION</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='header'>
    <img id='food' src='img/food.jpg'>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='colors'>
  <div id='top'>
    <div id='blue'></div>
    <div id='dark-green'></div>
  </div>
  <div id='bottom'>
    <div id='green'></div>
    <div id='orange'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Not sure what you're expecting to happen. You have a media query set to `960px` and below, and all your divs are set to 50%, but they aren't floating or in a flex parent element. There are a bunch of elements in your question. You should probably post just the bare minimum...for example, a single section with the CSS.

Comment: Thanks! I will edit the extras out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Mozilla cdn,

> The flex-basis CSS property sets the initial main size of a flex item.

So you can set width 50% rather than flex-basis 65% to resolve the above issue.

```
#dark-green {
  background-color: #29914c;
  max-width: 470px;
  height: 350px;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your colored `div`'s are not resizing at smaller viewport widths because you set [`flex-basis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis) to 65%. You can solve your problem by changing `flex: 0 0 65%` to `flex: 1 0`. This removes the `flex-basis` property, which is the third value in [flex shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex), and sets `flex-grow` equal to 1. You can also remove `width: 50%` in your media query, since `flex-grow: 1` achieves the same thing.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#blue,
#dark-green,
#green,
#orange {
  max-width: 470px;
  height: 350px;
  flex: 1 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#blue {
  background-color: #57afb5;
}

#dark-green {
  background-color: #29914c;
}

#green {
  background-color: #91e3ad;
}

#orange {
  background-color: #c98a32;
}

#top,
#bottom {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 2%;
}

.main-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.footer {
  margin-top: 8%;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}


/* responsive web design*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .footer {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

/*end of responsive web design*/
```

```html
<div class='main-content'>
  <div id='Navbar_Link-Toggle' style='font-size: 20px'>
    <i id='main' class='fas fa-bars'></i>
  </div>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='Navbar'>
      <a class='links' href=''>FOOD</a>
      <a class='links' href=''>FUN</a>
      <img id='center-logo' src='img/SAMO.png'>
      <a class='links' href=''>HISTORY</a>
      <a class='links' href=''>LOCATION</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='header'>
    <img id='food' src='img/food.jpg'>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='colors'>
  <div id='top'>
    <div id='blue'></div>
    <div id='dark-green'></div>
  </div>
  <div id='bottom'>
    <div id='green'></div>
    <div id='orange'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```